# UIImageView resize after present modally viewcontroller is dismissed?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, presentviewcontroller

Hi I have basic imageView with fix W and H constrains and they are set in interface builder in main VC. VC2 is loaded present modally on button SCORE, and thats fine. Its full screen VC2. Now on tap guesture it dismiss VC2 and return to main VC but the image is resize as you can see. Its smaller and bit to the left.

Am I missing something in code or in interface builder? I thought fix W and H would fix but not...

main VC first time: [image: main first time]

main VC after present modally is dismissed: [image: main VC after dimiss]

edited:

[image: constrains]

Comment: Post a screenshot of the interface builder showing your constraints. Also, a simple width and height constraint is not enough, a rectangle on the screen has 4 degree of freedom, so you'll have to specify also the position of the view.

Comment: @MrTJ edited constrains

Comment: It's really hard to say without seeing the rest of the code, but your problem might be that you fix the leading space to the layout margins (the thin blue line on the left edge), and these margins change somehow after the modal vc was dismissed. Try to remove the leading constraint and add instead a fixed width to the image view, and align the image view to the center of the image view instead of the button horizontally.

Comment: @MrTJ didnt help, if I make VC2 as push viewcontrller its OK, but if it is present modally it not. Maybe something is view VC2 present modally